# How to connect kafka IO from apache beam to a cluster in confluent cloud

Tags: python, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, confluent-cloud

I´ve made a simple pipeline in Python to read from kafka, the thing is that the kafka cluster is on confluent cloud and I am having some trouble conecting to it.

Im getting the following log on the dataflow job:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:820)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:631)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:612)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO$Read$GenerateKafkaSourceDescriptor.processElement(KafkaIO.java:1495)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
```

So I think Im missing something while passing the config since it mentions something related to it, Im really new to all of this and I know nothing about java so I dont know how to proceed even reading the JAAS documentation.

The code of the pipeline is the following:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import os
import json
import logging

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']='credentialsOld.json'

with open('cluster.configuration.json') as cluster:
    data=json.load(cluster)
    cluster.close()

def logger(element):
    logging.INFO('Something was found')  
      
def main():
    config={
        "bootstrap.servers":data["bootstrap.servers"],
        "security.protocol":data["security.protocol"],
        "sasl.mechanisms":data["sasl.mechanisms"],
        "sasl.username":data["sasl.username"],
        "sasl.password":data["sasl.password"],
        "session.timeout.ms":data["session.timeout.ms"],
        "auto.offset.reset":"earliest"
    }
    print('======================================================')
    beam_options = PipelineOptions(runner='DataflowRunner',project='project',experiments=['use_runner_v2'],streaming=True,save_main_session=True,job_name='kafka-stream-test')
    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as p:
        msgs = p | 'ReadKafka' >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config=config,topics=['users'],expansion_service="localhost:8088")
        msgs | beam.FlatMap(logger)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

I read something about passing a property java.security.auth.login.config in the config dictionary but since that example is with java and I´am using python Im really lost at what I have to pass or even if that´s the property I have to pass etc.

btw Im getting the api key and secret from here and this is what I am passing to sasl.username and sasl.password

[image]

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but when beam gets submitted, you'll need to modify the JVM arguments to include `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=...` system property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same error the first time I tried the beam's expansion service. The key `sasl.mechanisms` that you are supplying is incorrect, try with `sasl.mechanism` also you do not need to supply the username and password since you are connection is authenticated by jasl basically the consumer_config like below worked for me:

```
config={
        "bootstrap.servers":data["bootstrap.servers"],
        "security.protocol":data["security.protocol"],
        "sasl.mechanism":data["sasl.mechanisms"],
        "session.timeout.ms":data["session.timeout.ms"],
        "group.id":"tto",
"sasl.jaas.config":f'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required serviceName="Kafka" username=\"{data["sasl.username"]}\" password=\"{data["sasl.password"]}\";',
        "auto.offset.reset":"earliest"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe that little letter got me stuck for so long

Answer (score 0):

I got a partial answer to this question since I fixed this problem but got into another one:

```
config={
        "bootstrap.servers":data["bootstrap.servers"],
        "security.protocol":data["security.protocol"],
        "sasl.mechanisms":data["sasl.mechanisms"],
        "sasl.username":data["sasl.username"],
        "sasl.password":data["sasl.password"],
        "session.timeout.ms":data["session.timeout.ms"],
        "group.id":"tto",
        "sasl.jaas.config":f'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required serviceName="Kafka" username=\"{data["sasl.username"]}\" password=\"{data["sasl.password"]}\";',
        "auto.offset.reset":"earliest"
    }
```

I needed to provide the sasl.jaas.config porpertie with the api key and secret of my cluster and also the service name, however, now Im facing a different error whe running the pipeline on dataflow:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

This error shows after 4-5 mins of trying to run the job on dataflow, actually I have no idea how to fix this but I think is related to my broker on confluent rejecting the connection, I think this could be related to the zone execution since the cluster is in a different zone than job region.

UPDATE:

I tested the code on linux/ubuntu and I dont know why but the expansión service gets downloaded automatically so you wont get unsoported signal error, still having some issues trying to autenticate to confluent kafka tho.